# Need help organizing code [Android]

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

Here's the basic premise of my app: On start, it downloads `JSON` data and puts the `JSONObjects` in an array.

There are 3 fragments in a `ViewPager`. These fragments are the same fragment with a different position int so that the `ArrayAdapter` fills the list with data based on which position the fragment is in. Each fragment also has a `SwipeRefrehLayout` that should refresh the data and update all 3 list views.

The issue I'm running into is that I have to make a ton of calls across activities and fragments to do simple tasks. Right now I have my `MainActivity`, `Fragment`, `Constants`, `ArrayAdapter`, and `DataHandler` class. I feel like there is a *much* better way to do this without the convoluted code I currently have, but because I'm new to Android, I'm having a hard time figuring it out.

Any help is appreciated! 
Thanks :)

Comment: It's hard to give you an advice. Because your question(s) sounds like "how to develop good apps".

Comment: 1) Separate GUI classes from pure data classes. 2) Make a factory/singleton that returns you desired data, probably using static methods.

Comment: My main concern is how I'm initiating a refresh all the way through feeding it into the List. Right now, I'm calling the refresh data function in my `DataHandler`, calling a refresh list function in my `ArrayAdapter` to update the stored data and `notifyDataSetChanged()`. I'm doing this method because calling methods from fragments is proving to be more work than it's worth. Just seems like there's a more streamlined way to do it.

Comment: Also @m0skit0, I have never seen factories/singletons, so I'm hesitant to use them